# XCode 4 CpResource error

Tags: ipad, xcode4

When I build my app with Xcode 4 it always show this error message:

```
 CpResource "Color Calculator/X.png"    
 "/Users/mauro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Color_Calculator-eomtenpvfeomibgervrskkupofrx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Color Calculator.app/X.png"
```

It seems that Xcode wants to copy X.png in the DerivedData.

But I don't have X.png in my project. I use to have it, but it was deleted some versions ago (with many other png).
In order to verify, I deleted all the objects in project's xibs. So now I have two empty xib, however the error message continues to appear.

Thank you.

Comment: Found it!. The png was listed in target Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Click on your project, go in the tab "Build phase" then in the tab "Copy bundle ressources" and delete the .png to tell xcode to stop trying to copy it :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Copy-bundle-ressources]

In my case I removed the icon and added my "LAUNCH SCREEN and MAIN STRORY BOARD".